# On proving that a map is linear

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V\to W$ be a map on a vector space. To show that it is linear, one must show given $\vec{v},\vec{w}\in V$ and $a\in \mathbf{F}$ where $\mathbf{F}$ is the field which $V$ is defined over, that

- $T(\vec{v}+\vec{w})=T(\vec{v})+T(\vec{w}) \qquad $ (Additivity)
- $T(a\vec{v}) = a T(\vec{v}) \qquad $ (Homogeneity)

My question is whether the following equivalencies are sufficient prove linearity alone (that is, not to show additivity and homogeneity separately):

- $T(a\vec{v}+b\vec{w}) = aT(\vec{v})+bT(\vec{w})$

or

- $T(a\vec{v}+\vec{w}) = aT(\vec{v})+T(\vec{w})$

or

- $T(a(\vec{v}+\vec{w})) = aT(\vec{v})+aT(\vec{w})$

I ask this because sometimes it can be tedious to show both properties separately when the map is complicated.

Furthermore, when does it suffice to combine two properties into one statement and proving that statement also proves the properties which it is composed of?

Thanks

Comment: $T(a\vec{v}+\vec{w}) = aT(\vec{v})+T(\vec{w})$ is the equivalent version which is typically used.  $T(a\vec{v}+b\vec{w}) = aT(\vec{v})+bT(\vec{w})$ is an important version to be comfortable with.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you for the quick response. What is the reason that the second equivalency you mentioned would necessarily be more important than the first?

Comment: I think what you can generally do is  show that $T(c(x+y)) = cT(x)+cT(y)$ with $x,y$ being vectors. I think that is your first and third option. Not sure about the second one.

Comment: @Hushus46 "linear combinations" play a prominent role in linear algebra

Comment: @Marc the second is sufficient: set $\vec w = \vec 0$ for homogeneity and $a = 1$ for additivity

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Alright thank you. Would you like to post your comment as an answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second version, $T(a\vec{v}+\vec{w}) = aT(\vec{v})+T(\vec{w})$, is equivalent and is typically the most convenient form for proofs.

In order to see that a function satisfying the equation $T(a\vec{v}+\vec{w}) = aT(\vec{v})+T(\vec{w})$ (for all vectors $\vec v, \vec w$ and scalars $a$) is indeed linear, note that setting $\vec w = \vec 0$ shows that $T$ is homogeneous and setting $a = 1$ shows that $T$ is additive.